# I am unable to record in windows 7 ultimate 32 bits

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, microphone, recording

0

I have the following problem on Windows 7.

The built-in microphone on my laptop does not seem to be working. Either that (i.e., the mic hardware is not working) or it may be a software problem, i.e., the mic may be working hardware-wise, but the audio drivers or other software components in Windows that are responsible for working along with the mic to do audio recording are not working. Due to this, I have the following problems:

When on a Skype audio (or audio+video) call, when I talk, the other party is not able to hear me at all. Not even at low volume. But I am able to hear them just fine. Even video works fine both ways on Skype.

I am unable to record audio on my machine using any tool like Windows Voice Recorder or even YouTube My Webcam. But audio playback of music or other audio or video files is fine, e.g., using VLC Player. Normal beeps and other sounds for Windows or DOS error messages or warnings also work okay.

Comment: A Windows 7 computer is by definition pretty old, and computer hardware doesn't last forever.

Comment: You can no longer properly fix or update Windows 7 and 32-bit is pretty much gone. This is a poor base for modern concepts

Comment: Install Win10 and your mic will probably start working buddy!

Comment: @Mastaxx, It's doubtful a 32-bit machine could operate Win 10 with sufficient celerity to be functional. *Simplified:* Slow as molasses in winter.

Comment: Oh dear, i overlooked that little detail. True that brother.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You're assuming the machine is 32-bit based on the currently installed OS. Much more common in the Windows XP era but also occurred with Windows 7, many 64-bit PCs were sold with 32-bit Windows. Even later, the infamous Intel "Bay Trail" cheap laptops and tablet came with 32-bit Windows 8 (in a weird 64-bit CPU with 32-bit UEFI for which initially we'd need a special bootloader to be added to 64-bit Linux distros)

Answer (score 1):

If Windows 7 won't support Skype, try a Linux distro such as Ubuntu. One does not even need to install it to test:

- [Make](https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Live USB drive.
- Boot from the USB -- *Try*, not *Install*.
- [Install Skype](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/install-skype-ubuntu-16-04) on the running instance of Ubuntu. Note that unless you make the OS [persistent](https://calvin.me/create-persistent-ubuntu-16-04-live-usb-even-boots-ram/), changes will be lost after shutdown, but I do not recommend persistence on a flash drive because it is *s l o w*.
- If Skype works well on your PC from USB, install Ubuntu to the HDD, either dual-boot or by itself.
- Optional: you can upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04, the last 32-bit version, *after* installing 16.04 (there is no 32-bit 18.04 installer).

On an ancient (well, 2009) Acer D250 netbook, I find Ubuntu 18.04 still works well, faster and more reliable than the old OS. It runs Zoom, though I've not tried Skype.

Ubuntu also provides continuing security updates for 18.04 *via* [Ubuntu Pro](https://ubuntu.com/pro) through [2028](https://ubuntu.com/18-04), free for individual use, but Windows 7 is deprecated, unsupported and considered unsafe for network use.

As ChanganAuto states, there are other [32-bit Linux distros](https://www.makeuseof.com/linux-distros-with-32-bit-support/), too.

Comment: Debian still supports i386: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/i386/iso-dvd/

Comment: @ChanganAuto, yes, and there are others, https://www.makeuseof.com/linux-distros-with-32-bit-support/, but I suggested Ubuntu because of simple installer and using it for Zoom, though Skype I've not tried. That said,  any app running on generic Debian likely would on Ubuntu and *vice versa*.

Comment: Indeed. But iMO it's better to suggest current and supported releases than EoL Ubuntu that then needs to be release upgraded using archived repos and a somewhat unusual procedure and then apply for the extended support. With Debian is just install and run. Anyway, I'm still not convinced the author has a 32-bit machine as commented under the question. But I also feel we won't get any feedback. So here's my +1 for your work and time.

Comment: And +1 for making the point that, while Ubuntu 18.04 32-bit is still supported under Pro, it **is** past EOL. BTW, I regret Calibre dropping 32-bit support. (*sigh... I hate to see hardware wasted. Still have my ZX-81...*)

Comment: OP copy and pasted another question, chopping ogg parts of it the 0 at the beginning was a bit of a givaway. Not sure *why* tho, or why someone would spend the effort to slim down *someone elses* question but not clean up copy/pasting the *vote count*